# How to loop through multiple sub-collections of users in Firestore (React & Firebase web application)?

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I am making a React web application with Firebase as back-end. In the web application a fitness trainer can log his clients progression. Every week a trainer submits a form with some progress metrics (weight, blood-pressure etc.).

In Firestore I have a collection with all the clients of the trainer. Inside every client document is a collection with weekly progress metrics as shown below.

[image: Firestore setup]

[image: Firestore setup]

I want to set all the progress metrics of every client to a single useState so the trainer can export it to a csv-document. My plan was to do this with a useEffect where I loop through all the users progress forms, but I can't get it to work. Below is my current useEffect.

[image: useEffect]

It throws the following error:

[image: error]

How can I fix this so that all the progress forms are in a single useState?

Comment: Please include the relevant code and error messages as text, not as images.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For problems like this I always recommend keeping the reference documentation ready.

In this case, your `snapshot` variable is a [`QuerySnapshot` object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot), and each `doc` is a [`DocumentSnapshot` object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot). As you can see the `doc` does indeed not have a `collection` method as the error message also says.

You're looking for a [`DocumentReference` object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference), from which you can then get the [sub`collection`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#collection). To get from the snapshot to the reference, call `ref` on it.

So:

```
user.ref.collection("progress")...
```

Comment: That fixed the problem, thank you so much!